# Use nvvidconv to flip frame in 2 direction at the same time with Python OpenCV on Jetson Nano

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson-nano

According to docummentation [Accelerated_GStreamer_User_Guide_Release_24.2.1](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/embedded/L4T/r24_Release_v2.1/Docs/Accelerated_GStreamer_User_Guide_Release_24.2.1.pdf?t=eyJscyI6ImdzZW8iLCJsc2QiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY29tLyJ9), `nvvidconv` provide 7 method to flip the frame.

I want to do `nvvidconv flip-method=4` and `nvvidconv flip-method=6` at the same time. How should I write the gstreamer pipeline in `Python` with `cv2` on Jetson Nano?

The Code:

```py
import cv2

width = 640
height = 480
framerate = 30

gs_pipeline = f"v4l2src device=/dev/video0 io-mode=2 " \
              f"! image/jpeg, width={width}, height={height}, framerate={framerate}/1, format=MJPG " \
              f"! nvv4l2decoder mjpeg=1 " \
              f"! nvvidconv flip-method=[4, 6]  " \
              f"! video/x-raw, format=BGRx " \
              f"! videoconvert " \
              f"! video/x-raw, format=BGR " \
              f"! appsink drop=1"

gs_pipeline = gs_pipeline
print(f"gst-launch-1.0 {gs_pipeline}\n")

v_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gs_pipeline, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
if not v_cap.isOpened():
    print("failed to open video capture")
    v_cap.release()
    exit(-1)

while v_cap.isOpened():
    ret_val, frame = v_cap.read()
    if not ret_val:
        break

    cv2.imshow('', frame)

    input_key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if input_key != -1:
        print(f"input key = {input_key}")

    if input_key == ord('q'):
        break

v_cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flipping horizontally and vertically would be equivalent to 180° rotation, so just use:

```
... ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! ...
```